# Adding Primary and Foreign keys to SQL Table on Databricks

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, databricks, primary-key, azure-databricks

I'm new to Databricks and when I want to alter my SQL tables by adding primary or FK, I get an absurd error that can't seem to debug it.

```
%sql
ALTER TABLE samples_abp215dsdp ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY (SampleID);
```

here is the error message:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input '(' expecting {'CHECK', 'FOREIGN', 'PRIMARY', 'UNIQUE'}(line 1, pos 55)

== SQL ==
ALTER TABLE samples_abp215dsdp ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY (SampleID)
------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: According to the [databricks roadmap](https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D53f00001l4ucUCAQ), from March ... the foreign key support is supposed to be _sometime this year_, so the capability may not yet be available.

Comment: Appreciate it, Paul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spark do not have any concept of primary key. As spark is computation engine not database.

There are new features coming in **2022**. Follow below list:

- Unity catalog (seems that it will exists next to hive metastore and it will be possible to migrate)
- Control metastore, unity creations etc. from admin console,
- CPU clusters in "create cluster" (similar to SQL endpoints) where you specify how much cpus is needed
- Data lineage
- Delta sharing
- **Delta: primary keys**
- **Delta: foreign keys**
- Updated partner connect with many new partners joining
- Notebooks UI: transformations wizards (like select, drop, groupby from droplist etc.)
- New global search
- Integration of job service with git
- Jobs monitoring
- Repair and rerun failed tasks and pass values between tasks
- SQL workflows in SQL view
- create table enhanced via wizard
- Delta live tables in GA
- Serverless DBSQL
- Private links (to VNET and to ExpressRoute) and encryption
- ML: LightGBM, Prophet Models and Text Feature in Auto ML
- ML: Feature store integration with Azure MySQL, Azure SQL and CosmosDB
- ML: Feature store: point in time joins, time-based splits
- ML: Feature store API
- ML: Serverless model serving (enable serving button) with high availability SLA
- ML: one click model deployment into registry

In **2023**:

- Delta: identity column
- Delta: dynamic checkpoints and incremental commits to limit read/write operations with ADLS

Refer this [link](https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D53f00001l4ucUCAQ)

Comment: Identity columns is already GA: https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/10.4.html#identity-columns-support-in-delta-tables-is-now-generally-available

Comment: Are the foreign key enforced or just used as "annotation"?

Comment: @user3579222 Per docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/tables/constraints): "Primary and foreign keys are informational only and are not enforced."